# mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a specific data from the database that specific data should be the last entered ord_id. I saved it in a new variable called ord_id when the program runs i get this error Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in the error is in the line 35 it looks like this

addtocart.php

```
require_once 'config.php';
$config = new database();

$ord_id = mysqli_insert_id($config);

$data = $config->getData($ord_id);
foreach($data as $i){
    echo
        '<tr>
        <td> '.$i['ord_id'].'</td>
        <td> '.$i['card_id'].'</td>
        <td> '.$i['field1'].'</td>
        <td> '.$i['field2'].'</td>
        <td> '.$i['field3'].'</td>
        <td> '.$i['field4'].'</td>
        <td> '.$i['field5'].'</td>
        <td> '.$i['ord_qty'].'</td>
        <td> '.$i['card_price'].'</td>
        <td> '.$i['ord_total'].'</td>';

public function getData($ord_id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_order WHERE ord_id = :ord_id";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['ord_id' => $ord_id]);
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: What isn't clear about the error? You are passing an object of your own class to this function which expects an instance of MySQLi.

Comment: Pease share  source of database class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're calling `$this->con->execute()` implies that you're using PDO, not mysqli, so you can't call `mysqli_insert_id`. You should be using `$this->con->lastInsertId()`.

```
public function getOrdId() {
    return $this->con->lastInsertId();
}
```

Then you can use:

```
$ord_id = $config->getOrdId();
```

Note that this is only useful if you've performed an `INSERT` using the same database connection. It won't return anything useful if you call it immediately after `$config = new database();`.

Comment: it don't work it gives me this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property database::$con in i am trying a new method

Comment: If the property is private, you either need to add a `getCon()` method, or add a method that calls `mysqli_insert_id()` and returns the result.

Comment: i tried this function `public function getOrdid(){
  $ord_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->con);
  return $ord_id;
 }` but it gives me this error 
Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in this is how i called the function `require_once 'config.php';
      $config = new database();
      
      $ord_id = $config->getOrdid();
      
      $data = $config->getData($ord_id);
      foreach($data as $i)`

Comment: Why are you trying to call a mysqli function when you're apparently using PDO, not mysqli? I've updated the answer to show the correct method to use.

Comment: this code doesn't gives me any error and yes when type this after `$config = new database();` it doesn't gives me a result but without it i get an error where do i need to put it

Comment: It doesn't get an error, it just returns `0` if there was no insert.

Comment: You need to put it in the code that inserts the new row. It should return the ID to the client, which can then send it as a parameter in another call.

Comment: Ah ok this is my insert function `$config = new database();
 
 $config->insertData($total, $quantity, $card_id, $price, $field1, $field2, $field3, $field4, $field5);
 
 $config->getOrdid();
 //echo 'order'.$ord_id;
 
 header('Location: addToCart.php');` i implement this with a echo it returns a `ord_id` value but how can i get this value to another page because i redirect it to another page `addToCart.php` on that page it gives me an error saying undefined variable

Comment: Put it in a session variable. `session_start(); $_SESSION['ord_id'] = $config->getOrdid();`